# Not working java on Mac m2 MacBook Air (any jar sent error)

Tags: java, silicon

It used to work on the MacBook pro 14 on the m1 pro. But now it has stopped working on it too. This is an application for the operation of IP KVM Aten cs1708i. As soon as I click Connect, the program hangs and then gives an error. I did a full reset of the mac and the same thing. Please help - I've already tried everything I could.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/qs/570kgrkd07qf5r_67blv4d040000gn/T/libiKVMLib_V1.0.dylib
```

I tried to install various java builds (Azul,oracle, liberi). Java is installed - but the application does not work. **Mac Os Ventura OS**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First try to see if your system sees Java.  Go to a terminal and type

```
java -version
```

If it errors out, you need to add JAVA_HOME to your class path.  Your class path is where your system looks for commands.  Try google for installing java on your mac first and see how far you can get.  Come back if you need help.